# Combining categorical distributions derived from the same experiment but measured differently

Tags: probability, distributions, classification, categorical-data

I was wondering about how I should go about combining categorical distributions derived from the same experiment but measured differently.

Ex .....

Measurement A: 60% probability of label A, 30% probability of label B, 10% probability of label C

Measurement B: 30% probability of label A, 20% probability of label B, 20% probability of label C, 20% probability of label D, 10% probability of label D

......

Ideally, I would like the distribution to incorporate all labels and avoid non-zero probabilities.

Note, limitations to my experiment are that I do not have raw counts, just provided probabilities, and I do not know which labels exist until after the experiment

Thanks for the help

Comment: It may be confusing to use A/B for the two measurements' A/B/C for levels of the first, and A/B/C/D/ **E** for levels of the second. // Do you know how many use Meas 1 and how many use Meas 2.? // Do the two kinds of measurements try to measure the same thing? (Opinion or rating of the same thing? For example: product satisfaction, level of pain, degree of recovery, etc.?)

Answer (score 0):

If Yes to both of the questions in my comment, then suppose you have 100 with Method 1 and 100 with method 2. Then find midpoints of bins for Methods 1 and 2, using quantiles of bin boundaries.

Here is one possible way to combine the two samples of binned observations.

Combined, after some arithmetic, you have
new levels a through g with mid-bin quantile values $15, 30, 50, 60, 75, 80,$ and $95$ with respective counts (out of 200) as $30, 60, 20, 20, 30, 20,$ and $10+10=20.$

- The lowest bin $(0,30\%),$ label 'a' is from Method 2, and contains 30 subjects.
- For label 'b', bin $(0,60\%)$ with midpoint 30 from Method 2 contains 60 subjects; and so on.]

Then taking midpoint values and frequencies as
below, we have approximate mean quantile value $51,$ using
R as a calculator.

```
v = c(15,30,50,60,75,80,95)
f = c(30,60,20,20,30,20,20)
a = sum(f*v)/sum(f);  a
[1] 51
```

One could use R to simulate samples consistent
with this method, but each sample would
be somewhat different.

Because information is lost in binning the data,
you cannot know the exact sample mean of the combined sample. The mean for one possible sample is as follows:

```
set.seed(2022)
x = sample(v, 200, rep=T, prob = f)
mean(x)
[1] 52.4

table(x)
x
15 30 50 60 75 80 95  # values
34 50 22 22 26 18 28  # frequencies

summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   15.0    30.0    50.0    52.4    75.0    95.0
```

If we use R to simulate 10,000 such samples,
then the average of their mean scores is consistent
with the value 51 above.

```
set.seed(318)
a = replicate(10^5,
      mean(sample(v,100,rep=T,prob=f)))
mean(a)
[1] 50.99432
```

This histogram of these simulated scores is
nearly normal, possibly slightly skewed to the right.

```
hist(a,prob=T, col="skyblue2", 
 main = "Mean Scores of 10,000 Combined Samples")
  curve(dnorm(x, mean(a), sd(a)), add=T, col="orange", lwd=2)
```

[image]